# Change order using the "Switch Keyboard" (Globe) key on iOS screen keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

If you refer to the Apple KB [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/add-or-change-keyboards-iph73b71eb/ios), or to what other users seem to experience on the web (maybe because they have only 2 keyboards set up...), you would expect that the Switch Keyboard key  would do a circular shift of one increment in your list of set up keyboards in Settings each time you tap it.

For me it does not. Instead, the switching order seems rather random (I have 7 keyboards enabled). I can't get to understand the behavior or to find a pattern.

Has anybody the same issue? I am asking because daily I use only 2 or 3 of them, and it is "annoying" to open the full list by holding the button when typing.

Comment: I also have a few keyboard layouts enabled on my iPhone with iOS 13. I choose from the list when I have to switch. Only tapping on the switch key seems to bring one somewhat randomly.

Comment: Ok thanks @Alper we can generalize then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not actually random unless you’re experiencing a bug I haven’t seen. If you switch keyboards in fast succession, it cycles through the list in the same order as it’s presented when you hold. However, if you wait a second after switching the keyboard, the next time you press the globe button it goes BACK to the last keyboard you used (i.e. the last keyboard you kept open for a second or more). So if you don’t switch fast, you’ll end up switching between just two keyboards. I assume this is designed for bilingual people like me, but I agree that it’s confusing sometimes. One confusing consequence of this is that if I have keyboards A, B and C installed (ordered the same way in the list), I’m currently on B and before that I used A, then here’s what happens if I start quickly switching keyboards: it first goes to A because that’s what I last used, but then it SKIPS B and jumps to C, and from there starts cycling through the list. The full trajectory in this example ends up being B A C A B C A B C...

I would like an option to make the globe button cycle through only a subset of keyboards and make all other keyboards accessible only by holding.

Comment: Thank you I get it now! Indeed, your suggestion would be interesting! Another would be to have the globe icon on the emoji keyboard at the same place than the other ones. It would be easier to quickly cycle through keyboards by taping at the exact same spot on the screen.

Comment: @hymced mind accepting my answer? :)

Comment: sure sorry mate ;)